# Maximal open subset in which a function is injective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $H(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$ with domain all the plane except the origin. I was asked to study its injectivity and local injectivity. It is easy to note that $H(x,y) = H(-x,-y)$, so is not injective. Using the Inverse Function Theorem, it is possible to conclude that it is locally injective in all points of its domain, simply computing the determinant of the jacobian. I was wondering if it would be possible to find, for each point $(x,y)$, the maximal open subset in which $H$ is injective. This is because previously I studied the local injectivity of $G(x,y) = (e^x\cos{y}, e^x\sin{y})$, and I was able to find, for each point, maximal sets on which the funcion is injective. I want to know if it is possible to do the same for the function $H$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function is equal $f(z)=z^2$ for $z=x+iy.$ This should help.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I would like to solve it using only real analysis, since I encountered this doing Calculus exercises, but thanks for the input, I didn't realize that the functions were the parabola and the exponencial in complex numbers.

Comment: From my interpretation you can easily notice that $f(x,y)=f(x',y')$ if and only if $(x,y)=\pm (x',y')$ as $f(z)-f(z')=(z-z')(z+z').$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks! I understand now.